# Focus on latest agreement date from agreement table tableau

Tags: tableau-api

The data I am working to viz is calling data from a table that records  start_date, end_date and target_budget for a given design_id.  It's important to preserve how the target_budget and end_date changed over time. But for the most basic viz I only want to know end_date and target_budget for the latest date of record.  Below, you can see the end_date has been updated several times for design_id 2. My question is how would I report on only the end_date for the latest date_of_record?  I suspect that a LOD may be required but I'm not sure how to proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ FIXED [Design_ID], ({FIXED [Design_ID]: MAX([date_of_record])}) : MAX([End_Date]) }
```

The above will give you all the records of end date for the latest date of record.

If you just want one entry per record just put a MAX, like so:

```
MAX{ FIXED [Design_ID], ({FIXED [Design_ID]: MAX([date_of_record])}) : MAX([End_Date]) }
```

Comment: This comes close but fails if the end_date is updated to be earlier than previous end_dates.   That's why I want to report the end_date for the latest date_of_record.

Comment: I tried the updated but it did not meet the corner case. It fails if the end_date is updated to be earlier than previous end_dates.  I've updated the picture to show the results.

Comment: @TimothyLombard what exactly do you want? Max of end date on max of latest date of record.. or just max of end date?

Comment: Thank you for your focus.  What I want is the start_date, end_date and target_budget  for the latest date_of_record.

Comment: If you have multiple records of the mentioned `start_date, end_date and target_budget`, then do you want multiple records for the latest date of record or do you want max for all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202090/discussion-between-reinstate-monica-and-timothy-lombard).